# Hammock for Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, linkedin-api, restful-authentication, hammock

I have used **Hammock Package** for **LinkedIn Authentication** in **Windows Phone 8 Silverlight App.**

Now I am developing **Windows Phone 8.1 (WInRT) App**. **Hammock** is not supported. **Any replacements?**

Or can you please forward me link to tutorial on how to use linkedIn authentication in windows phone 8.1 without MVC and without Hammock?

```
using Hammock.Authentication.OAuth;
using Hammock.Web;


  internal static OAuthWebQuery GetRequestTokenQuery() //using Hammock.Authentication.OAuth;

    {
        SingletonClass singletonInstance = SingletonClass.MeraKyaHogaSingletonClassObject; //Singleton Instance


        var oauth = new OAuthWorkflow
        {
            ConsumerKey = singletonInstance.LinkedIn_consumerKey,
            ConsumerSecret = singletonInstance.LinkedIn_consumerKeySecret,
            SignatureMethod = OAuthSignatureMethod.HmacSha1,
            ParameterHandling = OAuthParameterHandling.HttpAuthorizationHeader,
            RequestTokenUrl = singletonInstance.LinkedIn_RequestTokenUri,
            Version = singletonInstance.LinkedIn_oAuthVersion,
            CallbackUrl = singletonInstance.LinkedIn_CallbackUri
        };

        var info = oauth.BuildRequestTokenInfo(WebMethod.Get); //using Hammock.Web;

        var objOAuthWebQuery = new OAuthWebQuery(info, false);
        objOAuthWebQuery.HasElevatedPermissions = true;
        objOAuthWebQuery.SilverlightUserAgentHeader = "Hammock";
        return objOAuthWebQuery;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Had same problem with Twitter. I choosed to use AsyncOAuth (https://github.com/neuecc/AsyncOAuth).

There's sample Universal app you can rewrite to use it with LinkedIn APIs - https://github.com/neuecc/AsyncOAuth/blob/master/AsyncOAuth.WindowsStoreApp/Twitter.cs.